# Direct communication between aspectJ aspects?

Tags: java, aspectj

i have a few different aspects in my application and i want them to be able to communicate. is it possible to somehow access one from another or the only way is to have some static field serving as a 'message board'?

i'm talking about aspectj, NOT spring aop. also i'm using the .aj files so i'm not limited by the annotation-only syntax

Edit:

To provide sample use case and the code i'm thinking about: Let's say i want to have different aspects guarding my banking app against  frauds. And i want them to communicate sometimes to decide together how to react on new types of timeseries and together change the fraud detection policy:

```
public aspect MyAspect1 {

  private MyState myState = ...

  pointcut myPointcut(): ...

  before(): myPointcut {
    MyAspect2 other = ... // how to get the reference to another similar aspect?

  }

}
```